# String was not recognized as valid Datetime after converting Db from MSSQL to SQLite

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime, sqlite

While playing with a code originally written for MSSQL ,i changed it to SQLite ,working well when it broke down to saying after `icommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

`String was not recognized as valid Datetime`

```
     try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MMIS.sqlite;Version=3;"))
            {

                String query = "INSERT INTO  tbl_Mdcl (Invoice_No,Invoice_Date,CustomerId,Med_Name,Comp_Name,Date_Manaf,Date_Exp,Qty,Price,Discount,Retail) VALUES (@Invoice_No,@Invoice_Date,@CustomerId,@Med_Name,@Comp_Name,@Manaf_Date,@Exp_Date,@Qty,@Price,@Discount,@Retail)";
                m_dbConnection.Open();
                using (SQLiteCommand icommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, m_dbConnection))
                {


                    ////a shorter syntax to adding parameter

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Invoice_No", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = InvoiceNo.Text.ToString();

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Invoice_Date", System.Data.DbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = PartId.Text;

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Med_Name", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = combomedicine.Text;

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Comp_Name", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = combocompany.Text;

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Manaf_Date", System.Data.DbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString();

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Exp_Date", System.Data.DbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString();

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Qty", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = qty.Text;

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Price", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = totl_prc;

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Discount", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = totldsc;

                    icommand.Parameters.Add("@Retail", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = retailpric;


                    var rowsaffected = icommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    MessageBox.Show("Record inserted. Please check your table data. :)");
                    ShowListView();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);

        }
```

The same code while having `SqlDbType.Date` as the second parameter of   `icommand.Parameters.Add(,)` worked well while changing it to `System.Data.DbType.Date` messed it.I'm at loss  even after consulting the documentation for `System.Data.DbType.Date`.
All other tweaks are working right now.

PS.The columns are set to Date im Db so no question of Datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parameter is of type date, why do you send a string as value? as far as I rememver, DateTimePicker.Value is of type DateTime. try it without the ToString() and see if that helps.

If not, use the ToString to provide a known format and use [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in the INSERT statement for this format. example:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TableName(DateColumn) VALUES (CONVERT(Date, @DateValue, 103)"; // 103 is this format: dd/mm/yyyy
SqlParameter DateParam = new SqlParameter("@Invoice_Date", System.Data.DbType.Char, 10);
DateParam.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
icommand.Parameters.Add(DateParam);
```

Comment: Why doesn't it matter to remove not `ToString()` from `DateTimePicker.Value` in MSSQL?

Comment: @JAVEDIQBAL: I don't understand what you are asking in this comment. the DateTimePicker is not a part of MSSQL, it's a part of your c# code (btw, winforms? web? wpf?) if it's value is indeed of type DateTime, then the value should pass as is between c# and sql server.

Comment: `DateTimePicker.Value.ToString()` is alright when the backend is supported by SQL unlikely SQLite where it needs `DateTimePicker.Value` only

Comment: So, bottom line, did it help or not?